# Adding UIView to UIActionSheet size not right

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiactionsheet

I am trying to add a view into an ActionSheet, but the dimensions are all messed up.

The view shows up, but when it doesn't show up with the correct size.
I made the View Width 300 by Height 411.

When I add it to the actionsheet using the code:

```
ContactCardViewController* myController = [[ContactCardViewController alloc] initWithNibAndEmployeeInfo:[self.request objectForKey:@"Requestor"]];

[self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[self.actionSheet setBounds:[myController.view frame]];
[self.actionSheet addSubview:myController.view];
```

Only about half the View shows and the right is slightly cut off, and it seems like it's almost the same size as the superview, which it should be a lot smaller.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not change** bounds, frame or center and add or modify subviews of `UIActionSheet`.

That is how you can fix that, because nobody knows internal implementation of this class and it definitely does not behave as normal `UIView`.